# Configuring multiple email to aliases in a config file

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2012

I have c# code which will be sending mails to a single user account or to a service account. Now I need to add multiple email aliases in "Email to " element so that mail will be sent to multiple aliases. I used semicolon(;) to separate each aliases but it is throwing error.

Here is my Code :

```
<appSettings>
<add key="MailFrom" value="fsdbm"/>
**<add key ="MailTo" value="abc@microsoft.com"/>**
<add key ="MailCC" value="abc@microsoft.com"/>

<add key ="FromPwd" value="Feb@2014"/>
<add key ="FromDomain" value="redmond"/>
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split email addresses manually :

```
var mailAddresses = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailTo"].Split(';');
foreach (var mailAddress in mailAddresses)
{
    //add each mailAddress to mail recipient list
}
```

Or if you're using [System.Net.Mail.MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), multiple email addresses should be separated by comma (`,`) instead of semicolon (`;`) :

```
var mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add("abc@microsoft.com,bcd@microsoft.com,cde@microsoft.com");
```